# VBA IE Automation - Can't click a button with Event Listener mouseenter and mouseleave

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, automation

Anyone can help me? I'm having problem clicking a button with EventListener "onmouseenter" and "onmouseleave". I already tried FireEvents and DispatchEvents but nothing works. I cannot post the HTML source code as it's a client website, but what I've noticed is that every time I manually click on the button the class attribute is changing, does it have a connection to my issue or is there a way that I can also control that changes?

[image]

Comment: Please read what it takes to provide us with a [mre]. Thanks!

Comment: You can make a minimum amount of changes in the source before posting, and your VBA is also important here.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample code for your requirement based on your above description.

```
Sub demo()

    '--Add reference to Microsoft Internet controls and Microsoft HTML Object library...

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument

    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate2 "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\189.html"

    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    Set objLink = IE.document.getElementById("myBtn")
    objLink.FireEvent ("onclick")
    objLink.FireEvent ("onmouseenter")
    objLink.FireEvent ("onmouseleave")

    Stop
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

If still issue persist than I suggest you to create sample HTML and VBA code which can produce the issue on our side. We will try to test it and try to provide suggestion for it.

We do not require any personal or confidential information about you or your client.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, I will try this and let you know if there will still be any issue.

Comment: I tried the suggestion above and it is still not working. I updated my question by adding picture of the source code of one of the element button. The main element is <a> and there are <div><span> element inside it. The EventListener are also attached on the anchor element.

Comment: I suggest you to do not post an image of the code. because it is not helpful for analyzing and finding the issue also we cannot make a test with an image. We are not able to get any idea about the issue using that image. I suggest you to develop a sample code which can produce the issue. We can test it and try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.